# Remove duplicates based on a specific criteria for date/time

Tags: excel, vba

Excel Data

[image: 1]

I have a massive data set in which I need to remove duplicates based on a specific criteria for date & time.

Criteria - to retain the record with closest time in TouchedWhen column to HospEntryDate.

So, for instance for ID 852852, I would want to keep row # 8 (TouchedWhen: 8/17/2023 7:50 ; HospEntryDate: 8/17/2023 7:55)

Tried grouping them by Query Editor using Table Max & Min, but does not work for all scenarios.
Also tried a formula - =IF(COUNTIFS(C:C, "<"&D58,D:D, ">"&C58), "Delete", "Keep")
But again this formula does not work for all IDs.

Comment: have you tried any of these methods? https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/remove-duplicates-excel

Comment: You may need to calculate the time difference in minutes https://www.exceltip.com/excel-dates/calculate-number-of-minutes-between-dates-time-in-microsoft-excel.html

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: How about row 2 and 3? Keep one or remove all?

Comment: Row 16 & 17 are the exact same, 13 & 14 have the only difference of "White" <-> "North am", what do you do with those duplicates?

Comment: Which columns are taken into account when determining if a row is a duplicate or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ABS(D2-C2)=ABS(AGGREGATE(15,6,(D:D-C:C)/(A:A=A2),1)),"Keep","Delete")
```

It will only check for ID, so it's not code sensitive. Any draw will still remain. All within the specification you've granted so far.

If you want also to cut off any draw, you can save just the first occurence of the minimum time difference for a given ID with this formula:

```
=IF(ABS(D2-C2)=ABS(AGGREGATE(15,6,(D:D-C:C)/(A:A=A2),1)),IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$E$1:E1,"Keep")=0,"Keep","Delete"),"Delete")
```